# Download Files in iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing mobile app by using nativescript with angular. I want to download files in user accessible location. It is OK in Android no matter what file type is. And also OK in iOS if the file type is image by using imagepicker plugin. But for other file type, I can't find the proper way to implement.
According to the reading, I can save pdf file by sharing on Books which is default app in iOS.

If so, do I try to access apps in iOS to save files?
I am confused!:(

If you have implemented the above case, please show me the way how can I implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use **nativescript-downloader** plugin for download the file in nativescript iOS and android mobile app. [Nativescript Market Url](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-downloader)

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. But I want to save the file in user accessible location. The plugins you mentioned is not working in Nativescript with Angular.